# SpringRunner TestRestTemplate does not return Security Headers

Tags: spring, junit, spring-security, spring-boot-test

I am using getForEntity of TestRestTemplate. However it does not return TLS, HSTS or HPKP headers I configure inside my WebSecurityConfig class. It does however work in real world environment. Why is the security filter chain not invoking during test?

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class SecurityTest {

@Autowired
private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

@LocalServerPort
private String portNumber;

@Test
public void testHeaders() {

    ResponseEntity<?> response = this.restTemplate.getForEntity(
            "/path/does/not/exist", Object.class);

    HttpHeaders responseHeaders = response.getHeaders();
    Set<Map.Entry<String, List<String>>> headers = responseHeaders.entrySet();

    headers.stream().forEach((entry) -> {
       assert entry.getKey().equals(SOMETHING_VALUABLE);
    });
}
```

}